# Using promise within generators

Tags: javascript, generator, bluebird, es6-promise

I'm having a issue with my promise being returned within my generator when I attempt to iterate on it. I'm using the NPM Twitter module, and promisifying it with Bluebird.js. It is to my understanding that when I call the first g.next(), the program will execute until the yield statement, then eveluate to the right. Upon the second next() call, the program would then assign the value returned from the promise into the x variable. Instead, I'm getting a value of undefined, even when I try to log the value of 'x' within the function. The first g.next() does log out a object displaying that i did return a successful promise (see screenshot below). Maybe I'm thinking about this all wrong, but I'm really confused on how this does not work. Any and all help will be greatly appreciated.

```
var Promise = require('bluebird');

var Twitter = require('twitter');

var client = 
Promise.promisifyAll(
new Twitter({
  consumer_key: '*********',
  consumer_secret: '********',
  access_token_key: '********',
  access_token_secret: '******'
}));


function *go(){

  var x = yield client.getAsync('statuses/user_timeline');
  console.log(x);

};


var g = go();

console.log(g.next().value);
console.log(g.next().value);
```

Screenshot:

[image]

Comment: "*the program would then assign the value returned from the promise into the x variable*" - no, why would it? It assigns the value that you pass to `.next()` (which *is* `undefined` in your case). It sounds like you want to use `Promise.coroutine` which runs the generator for you.

Comment: Gotcha, see I thought it would assign the evaluated expression from the yield, upon calling .next() again. so if I had : var y = yield 2+2, I thought the first .next() would evaluate the yield to 4, then when called again, it would take that 4 and assign it to the vaiable 'y'.

Comment: Kind of like how this guy did, (look at last example): https://davidwalsh.name/es6-generators

Comment: As I said, use `Promise.coroutine` from Bluebird. You don't want to write [this](https://davidwalsh.name/async-generators) manually, and lift it into promises.

Comment: Thanks a lot, it worked ! But can you possibly give me an explanation as to why ?

Comment: `Promise.coroutine` internally does something like `g.next().value.then(function(res) { g.next(res).value.then(…); })` (but considers all edge cases and is more performant)